# What is the burning building this character walks past in the city?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-the-dragon

Trying to ask with as few spoilers as possible.

In *House of the Dragon* season 1 episode 9 "The Green Council",

> Rhaenys gets out of the Red Keep, then

walks in the city and passes a building which is burning.

[image]

Is this building significant in any way? Was it set on fire on purpose by someone?

Answer (score 12):

I haven't watched it but found this article:

https://www.distractify.com/p/whose-house-was-burning-house-of-the-dragon-episode-9

> [...] we hope Mysaria (Sonoya Mizuno) has good homeowner's insurance. But why was her house burning? Let's just say it wasn't an accident. Remember who played with fire earlier in the season and got every other male in his family burned ... alive?
>
> That's right — Larys Strong (Matthew Needham) was the culprit behind Mysaria's unplanned house barbecue.
>
> During the now infamous feet scene, Larys reveals to Alicent that there's a web of spies keeping tabs on everything in the Red Keep. He informs Alicent that one of the spies in question is her maid, Talia (Alexis Raben).
>
> Larys slyly suggests that the spy network could be destroyed ... if the queen leading the charge is destroyed. Without further questioning, Alicent essentially orders Larys to take care of it.

Comment: Another plot point is this 'story' you cannot figure out just by watching :\

Comment: @Tetsujin Of course you can: they showed that house and its balcony in an earlier episode.

Comment: @BCdotWEB correct, I thought I recognized it, but I wasn't sure and I don't think it is made clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it yourself at the end of the previous episode, S01E08:

[image]

[image]

It's house of the White Worm, the lady Mysaria. Then you can see Talya bringing message from the castle.

The fire was plotted by Alicent and Lord Larys in S01E09, to destroy the head of the web of spies.